# DB2 save CLOB (>16Mb) into IFS

Tags: xml, db2, ibm-midrange, rpgle, ibm-ifs

I'm trying to save the content of a field(CLOB) into a file on the IFS (iSeries).

The file doen't exist before save the content and the file is created perfect, but I don't know why at the begining (always position 1 and 2) the file contains two odd characteres. This characteres aren't always the same.

I think it's a problem with the conversion between clob field an the file (ifs - smtf)
Does anyone how to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!!

PD.:Sorry, I coudn't attach an image because I need at least 10 reputation to post images.

---

Variable Definiton in RPGLE

```
D xmlEntrada      s                   sqltype(CLOB:10000000)

fd = open('/folder/file/file.xml': 
O_WRONLY+O_CREAT+O_TRUNC: 
O_RDWR : 819);                                                

callp write(fd: %addr(xmlEntrada)+2: %len(xmlEntrada));
```

Comment: you can post a link to a photo bucket image service.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_3t1a8hlFj4T0lVQWhpMXh2NXM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The characters odd are " A" berfore the first tag "<SGA..."

Comment: Two odd characters sounds like the 'length' portion of a variable length character field.  Can you edit the question to show how you are saving the CLOB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [English RPG manual](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/rzasd/varyprefix.htm) calls this the 'Length-Prefix'.  This is 2 bytes for a variable between 1 and 63353 bytes, and 4 bytes for larger variables.  Change the write() to:

```
write(fd: %addr(xmlEntrada: *DATA): %len(xmlEntrada));
```

and let the [compiler determine the length-prefix size](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/rzasd/bbaddr.htm%23bbaddr).

If on an earlier release, try

```
write(fd: %addr(xmlEntrada)+4: %len(xmlEntrada));
```

Comment: I tried but now, I have an Error: "*RNF0229 20 1 *DATA sólo es válido para %ADDR cuando la definición es un elemento de longitud variable; *DATA se ignora. " --> * DATA RNF0229 is only valid for% ADDR when the definition is an element of variable length; * DATA is ignored.

Comment: OK so you're on an earlier release.  Make it %addr(xmlEntrada)+4

Comment: I spend many hours to find a solution. Finally I did an alternative thank you for help me. I use this solution. Thanks again!!

Comment: @BuckCalabro Upvoted and suggest editing to include your "%addr()" comment in the answer.